# How do I access variables outside a setIntervall function in vue.js?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

How can I access showOverlay from inside my setIntervall method?
I'm getting coordinates from my backend, I expect these coordinates to check for the right node and then show an overlay with vuetify.

```
data: () => ({
    success: false,
    showOverlay: false,
    coordinates: {
      x: 0,
      y: 0
    },
    nodeArray: ['c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'a', 'b','c_octave'],
    displayedNode: 'd',

  }),
    checkPosition(node) {
      var that = this;
      var intervalid = null;
      var varCounter = 0;
      var varName = function () {
        if(varCounter <= 10) {
          console.log(node)
          console.log(that.coordinates.x)
          varCounter ++;
          if(that.coordinates.x> 50) {
            console.log('inside')
            that.showOverlay = true;
            that.success = true;
            that.Sleep(2000)
            that.showOverlay = false;

...

          } else if((that.coordinates.x > 350 || that.coordinates.x < 400) && node === 'c_octave') {
            that.showOverlay = true;
            that.success = true;
            that.Sleep(2000)
            that.showOverlay = false;

          }
        } else {
          clearInterval(intervalid);
        }
      }
      setInterval(varName,1000);

    },
    Sleep(milliseconds) {
      return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, milliseconds));
    },
```

Comment: Is your problem solved or still pending?

Answer (score 1):

Change the function to use a `fat arrow` to maintain the context of `this`:

```
var varName = () => {
  //..everything else
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to access the `this` in Vue component instance context. By using the old `function` keyword, you've changed the `this` context to that "function", to not change the context, you could use ES6 arrow function syntax instead. `var varName = () => {}` instead of `var varName = function () {}`. Basically that's **the main difference between function declared by function keyword vs ES6 arrow function**.